# 2 ESXi servers: NFS for storage, second for VMs. Startup considerations

Tags: vmware-esxi, nfs, automation

I'm planning to test this configuration:

- server A - ESXi with virtual ZFS storage appliance exported as NFS,
- server B - ESXi with Datastore2 connected to NFS, VM files on Datastore2.

How to accomplish proper startup procedure: `A -> napp-it-> B -> conect and mount NFS -> VM1,  VM2`. A and B can start at the same time, napp-it can autostart but VM1 must wait for the Datastore2 will be available.

Answer (score 0):

There are various approaches. Probably the simplest ones are:

1. have a small VM on host A set to auto start with the host and check storage startup, then power up host B through IPMI or simply WOL
2. (implies host is installed on local storage) power up host B automatically but set all VMs for manual start; then with a small VM on either A or B check storage and power up the VMs through the API
3. (requires proper ESXi licensing) set VM1, VM2, ... as dependent on the napp-it VM (e.g. as agent VM)

Comment: I have ended with autostart with: VM-STORAGE, VM-DUMMY-DELAY, and all other VMs. Dummy delay is small, empty VM with start delay parameter set to 300s, enought to warm up storage.